# Is it possible to convert a c++ string into actual code?

Tags: c++, string

Is it possible to take a string like this:
 `string code = "std::cout<<"Hello World";"`

And somehow make the code within the string run?

Comment: AFAIK, only by calling an operating system function to invoke a compiler process to create a shared library to dynamically load and execute.  Vaguely possible that clang be able to be linked as a library into the running C++ executable and improve on that though - I haven't kept tabs.  It's more common for people to embed an interpreter for some other language, like Lua or python.

Comment: I am sorry to say that I didn't understand a word.

Comment: Short version is no.  Long version: you know you can use your compiler to create a shared library?  You could use say `popen()` or `system()` to run the compiler from your program, then open the library using `dlopen`, get a pointer to the code you want to run using `dlsym`.

Comment: Damn thats a bummer

Comment: @FlimsyEar665012 What are you really trying to accomplish?  This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: There are some convoluted ways to do it, like launching the compiler from your own program, but they probably aren't worth the effort.

Comment: here you can find a c++ interpreter, I'd expect that it is still a major effort to make use of it in your own application: https://github.com/root-project/cling

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie What I am trying to do is make a game but I want to allow custom inputs by the player to make custom inputs for moves which would then be stored on a json. So now I need to know how can I allow the player to create as many inputs as they want and let the game do the behind the scene work and check for input presses.

Comment: The solution that came to mind was making the json store code and run that code in the program but that doesnt work so now I am trying to find another solution. It might make no sense why I went with this approach but it was the only thing that came to mind atm.

Comment: for scripting to allow customization you typically don't use C++ (even if it would be possible somehow, most of C++ power is coming from not being interpreted but compiled). I know that lua is commonly used for such customization scripting

Comment: Yeah. So basically no unless I want to make a compiler.

Comment: Your C++ app can host a scripting environment, such as LUA, Microsoft ActiveScript (which can run JScript and VBScript), etc and then it can simply execute scripts when needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau C++ interpreters do exist https://github.com/root-project/cling

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili i don't know cling, only its predecessor, and that was not very fun to work with, it wasn't really C++ but it had its own quirks and restrictions

Comment: @idclev463035818 It had problems with scoping if I recall correctly. My point is languages aren't inherently compiled or interpreted, even though C++ is clearly meant to be compiled.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to take a string like this:  string code = "std::cout<<"Hello World";"
>
> And somehow make the code within the string run?

Certainly.

First, output the string and pipe the output as input into another program. This other program should take the input and interpret it as a C++ and produce an executable. Such program is called a compiler (technically, assembler and linker are also needed but let's assume that they are invoked by the compiler automatically). Lastly, run the executable produced by the compiler.